# Find a pair of natural numbers who have the least energy among all pairs having sum of n

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures

There is a natural number n. You have to find a pair of natural numbers x, y whose sum is n and also have the least energy among other pair having the sum n.

```
Energy(x) = sum of all digits of x
Total Energy = Energy(x) + Energy(y)

1 <= n <= 10^9

For eg, 
n = 10000
A few pairs: 
5000 + 5000 -> Energy = 10
1000 + 9000 -> Energy = 10
9999 + 1 -> Energy = 37
2999 + 7001 -> Energy = 37

So possible answers are:
(5000, 5000), (1000, 9000) etc
```

I have tried the solution noted above so far but it is not an optimized approach

I will loop from 1 to n-1 and and try all pairs and check their sum of digits but it will take too much time for big numbers.
e.g.

```
n= 50

1,49--> energy 14
2,48--> energy 14
3,47--> energy 14
4,46--> energy 14
5,45--> energy 14
.
.
.
.
10,40-->energy 5
```

(Edited) After some thought, I arrived at the following solution. Would appreciate if somebody can come up with a better solution

```
public int sum(int n) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    if (isNonZeroOnlyOne(n)) {
        int num = getNonZeroNo(n);
        if (num == 1)
            return 10;
        return num;
    }
    return calculateEnergy(s);
}

private int calculateEnergy(String s) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        sum += s.charAt(i) - '0';
    return sum;
}

private int getNonZeroNo(int n) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c != '0')
            return c-'0';
    }
    return '0';
}

private boolean isNonZeroOnlyOne(int n) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c != '0')
            count++;
        if (count > 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Create two methods for this: one for calculating the sum of the digits, and one to check if the sum is the same as the energy. Beyond that, it wouldn't be very cash money of me to give you the answer outright.

Comment: Please include your attempt at solving this problem, and why it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a _question_ your post should actually contain one and ideally also show what you've did so far (code, research, thoughts) and where you failed and why. Further reference: [ask]

Comment: Please suggest something apart from brute force

Comment: "Please suggest something apart from brute force" - note that SO is not a gimme-teh-codez site so we won't do your work for you (and that includes research). Please show some effort on your side first or your question risks being closed for lack of effort.

Comment: @AyeshnaRai There really isn't a method apart from brute forcing. Unless your question is how to make an AI that can solve this problem on its own, I suggest using the simplest method.

Comment: I've updated the post with my approach

Comment: Surely there is a better way than brute force. As a hint, think about how many times you have to "carry a 1" in the sum to make n.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple.

if n is of type 10^x then the answer is 10. otherwise answer is the sum of digits of n.

The idea here is to break down the number into a pair containing digits less than that are present in n. if you break down into smaller digits then sum remains the same as the original number. 
example for 7= 1-6,2-5,3-4.

for a number like 100, 1000....
digit 1 can't be broken down into further pairs, so we try to make 10 as the sum of digit so that the sum becomes n.
like for 10=5-5,2-8,3-7
100=20-80,40-60

for other numbers, like 123
it can be broken into 100-23, 120-3, 111-12... all will give you sum 6. which is the sum of digits of the original number.

if you try to break down into further pairs like 80-43, 52-71, you will see that the digit sum increases as you broken down to a number containing digits which is higher than those are present in n. like 8 4,5,7 are greater than 3.

Answer (score 1):

The least energy can be derived by a simple formula.

1) Given N >  100, the pair can be  N-100 and 100 , and the energy will be same as the energy of N. 
eg :  N = 500 ;  Pair = 400 and 100 ; Energy = 5

2) N >=10  and N <=100 , pair = N-10 and 10
eg :  N = 50 ;  Pair = 40 and 10 ; Energy = 5

3) N >=2 and N <=10 , pair = N-1 and 1
eg :  N = 5 ;  Pair = 4 and 1 ; Energy = 5

Comment: If N = 10000, then N-100 = 9900 and the pairs would be (9900, 100), hence energy would be 19 of this pair, which is not minimum. But the minimum of 10000 is 10, and pairs like (2000, 8000), (4000, 6000) etc

Comment: The below logic will cover all scenarios

if N%10 == 0  
 then 
 x1= (N/10) and x2 = N-x1
Else
 x1 = N-10 and x2 = 10

Answer (score 0):

I spent more than 1 hour on this problem. What should be answer for `n = 1`? So I think `n` should be greater than *1*. I am assuming `n > 1`.

So brute-force solution won't work here because `n` is huge enough. So you need more optimized solution. You need to think think about how many times you have to `carry 1` in the sum to make `n`. It is at most `9` times!

If you have some basic idea with `digit-dp(Dynamic Programming)` then this problem is easy. Try to place all possible digit on a place of n and take **minimum** energy among them. This problem is easy when you fully understand `digit-dp` technique. You can learn it from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digit-dp-introduction/) and [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53960).

For practice, you can find a lot of problems [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/67679) (**Dynamic programming** section).

For your references, I wrote this code just now and it is working properly. Hope you can use this as a reference.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

const string INF_STRING = "9999999";
const int INF_INT = 9999999;

pair<string, int> INF = make_pair(INF_STRING, INF_INT);

int nod;
int digits[10];

int num_of_digits(int a) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while(a) {
        digits[cnt] = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

pair<string, int> dp[10][2][2][2];

pair<string, int> solve(int ind, int carry, bool is1, bool is2) {
    if(ind >= nod) {
        if(carry != 0 ||  !is1 || !is2) return INF;
        return make_pair("", 0);
    }
    pair<string, int> &ret = dp[ind][carry][is1][is2];
    if(ret.second != -1) return ret;
    ret = INF;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int s = (i + j + carry);
            pair<string, int> cur = INF;
            if(s % 10 == digits[ind]) {
                cur = solve(ind + 1, s / 10, is1 || (i > 0? 1:0), is2 || (j > 0? 1:0));
            }
            if((cur.second + i + j) < ret.second) {
                ret.second = cur.second + i + j;
                ret.first =  cur.first + (char)(i + '0');
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int stringToInt(string num) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<num;
    int ret;
    ss >> ret;

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int i, t, cases = 1, j, k, pos;
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    nod = num_of_digits(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            dp[i][j][0][0] = make_pair(INF_STRING, -1);
            dp[i][j][0][1] = make_pair(INF_STRING, -1);
            dp[i][j][1][0] = make_pair(INF_STRING, -1);
            dp[i][j][1][1] = make_pair(INF_STRING, -1);
        }
    }

    pair<string, int> res = solve(0, 0, 0, 0);

    string num1_str = res.first;
    int num1 = stringToInt(num1_str);
    int num2 = n - num1;

    printf("Minimum Energy: %d\n", res.second);
    printf("Num1 = %d, Num2 = %d\n", num1, num2);


    return 0;
}

/*
Input:
10000

Output:
Minimum energy: 10
Num1 = 1000, Num2 = 9000

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in javascript in simple way.

```
function calculateEnergy(n) {
  let e = 0    
  while(n > 0) {
    e += n % 10
    n = Math.floor(n / 10)
  }
  return e
}


function countMinEnergy(n) {
  let minE = n
  let i = 1
  while(i <= n/2) {
    let e = calculateEnergy(i) + calculateEnergy(n - i)
    minE = e < minE ? e : minE
    i++
  }
  return minE
}
```

countMinEnergy(4325)

Answer (score 0):

Here is scala solution

```
object LeastEnergyPair extends App {
    
      private def getCountOfPair(array: Array[Int],sum: Int): mutable.Set[(Int, Int)] = {

    val seen =  mutable.Set[Int]()
    val out = mutable.Set[(Int,Int)]()

    array map { x =>
      val target = sum - x
      if (seen.contains(target) || target*2 == sum)
        out += ((Math.min(x,target),Math.max(x,target)))
      else
        seen += x
    }
    println(out)
    out
  }


  private def sum(i:Int): Int = i.toString.toCharArray.map(_.asDigit).sum


  def findLeastEnergyPair(a: mutable.Set[(Int,Int)]): (Int,Int) = {
    var min = Int.MaxValue
    var minPair = (0,0)
    a.foreach {
      case (i,j) =>
        if (sum(i) + sum(j) < min) {
          min = sum(i) + sum(j)
          minPair = (i,j)
          println(s"$min ----- $minPair")
      }
    }
    minPair
  }

  println(findLeastEnergyPair(getCountOfPair((1 to 10000).toArray, 10000)))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below logic will cover all scenarios

```
if (N%10 == 0) {

      x1= (N/10);
      x2 = N-x1
}else{

     x1 = N-10; 
     x2 = 10;
}
```